# SwiftUI fit text to image container

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I tried to create a simple widget that is an image with text on top of it. But from time to time, text is cropped and text does not wrap to a new line (see screenshot).

What should I do to prevent it?

```swift
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Image("Bg")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
        .overlay(
          VStack {
            Text("Long text...")
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .shadow(color: .black, radius: 20, x: 0, y: 10)
              .font(.system(size: 18))
              .padding(16)
          }
        )
    }.widgetURL(getDeepLink())
  }
```

[image]

Comment: tried "contentMode: .fit" ?

Comment: `contentMode: .fit` will add empty spaces. I need to cover all widget space with image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because the overlay is set on the fill image frame.
You can use overlay on Text to add image or:

```
Text("Long text... Long text... Long text... Long text... Long text...")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 20, x: 0, y: 10)
        .font(.system(size: 18))
        .background(
             Image(systemName: "cloud")
                 .resizable()
                 .scaledToFill()
                 .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

Comment: I tried `GeometryReader` & `Image().frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)` and seem it also works